# Android get actual request text when submitting POST request

Tags: android, http, post, text, request

I would like to get actual text that is send when I submit a`POST` request. Like I can look it up in Chrome with Developer Tools and see the requests actual source code.

I am sending my request using this code:

```
public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
                                   HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "ASP.NET_SessionId=3rzu2e01orktggfon4oybwax; captcha=disabled");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            //Vrnjen HTML
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
    //Iz hashMap naredi paraetre in jih pošle preko POST
    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

I do get a returned html. But i would like to see the actual request txt.

Is there any function that would allow me to do that?